# Replacing hover, for a click event css only

Tags: css, hover

On this link, instead of hovering the mouse over the image, I wanted to make the other images appear only when I click in the main image. I tried replacing the pseudo class for target, focus, but none of them worked. Is there a way to do this with css only? Because my CMS doesn't allow me to insert javascript.

Thanks,
Bruno

Comment: You have no link in your post. But i think, it can not be done with css.

Comment: I don't think it's possibly without JS. Does the CMS not allow inline scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this. There is one problem where links do not register **:focus** events, it will register them if you navigate to the link with TAB. But that would be a problem for the users. Anyway you can use that to overcome the problem. Just place **tabindex** on your link

```
<a href="#" tabindex="0">
    <img src="1.png">
</a>
```

On your CSS:

```
a:focus img{
    content:"xxx";
    width:XXpx;
    height:XXpx;
    /*Whatever you need here*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Stuff you can do with the “Checkbox Hack”](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/)

It is possible to do in combination with HTML, not just css. You will have to take use of the checked css event in combination with `<label>` element, you will also have to have some checkbox hidden somewhere in the document. It is quite hacky and its all described in the article.